# Batching Working but is misssing the final record gets 15 instead of 16 Reocrds

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Ok So I have this working to a point its grabbing all 15 records in a batch of 5 but their is 16 records how do to get the 16th record. Obv I want to keep the calls to the web services down to  a Min so how would i go about get the last record bare in mind it may not always be one their could be 19 records which means I would need to get the last four?.

```
                Dim batchCount As Integer = 0
            For Each thisentry In orderLineData.Rows

                If recordCount >= cfb.PacketBatchSize Then
                    batchCount = batchCount + 1

                End If
                filenameSplit = thisentry.Item("unqiueFilename").ToString().Split("_")
                batchNumber = recordCount + 1

                batchNumberpad = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenameSplit(2)) & "_" & batchCount.ToString("D3") & ".csv"
                With request

                    .companyID = settings.companyID

                    .machineID = settings.machineID

                    .uniqueBatchIdentifier = batchNumberpad

                End With



                ' For Each thisentry2 In orderLineData.Rows
                With pushOrderIncQTY

                    .costPrice = thisentry.Item("costPrice")
                    .externalTimeStamp = DateTime.Now()
                    .RootPLU = thisentry.Item("tagbarcode") 'set this to the barcode from the file
                    .sizeBit = -666
                    .supplierID = cfb.SupplierID
                    .orderReference = thisentry.Item("OrderNumber")
                    .orderLineReference = ""
                    .externalTransaction = ""
                    .sourceShop = cfb.SiteId 'set to the GEMINI location ID for this store (you will have to get this from your configuration file
                    .destinationShop = cfb.SiteId 'set this to the same as the sourceshop
                    .QTY = thisentry.Item("ActQty")
                    .whichQty = LiveSales.infoPushOrderIncQTY.Which_OrderQty.delivered 'only available option at present

                End With
                recordCount = recordCount + 1

                pushOrderInQty.Add(pushOrderIncQTY)
                If recordCount >= cfb.PacketBatchSize Then
                    batchCount = batchCount + 1

                    CallWebSerivce(wrpPush, request, pushOrderInQty.ToArray())

                    pushOrderInQty.Clear()
                    recordCount = 0


                End If

            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 conditions for sending a batch: a) you have reached batchsize OR b) you are processing the last row in which case, you want to send a partial.  One way to do that would be to change the FOR EACH loop to a For N loop.  Assuming that `orderLineData` is a DGV, you could change your loop to something like this:

```
Dim nLastRow As Integer = orderLineData.Rows.Count - 1
For n as Integer = 0 To nLastRow
    ' your code here

    ' will have to change thisentry references to row references

    If (recordCount >= cfb.PacketBatchSize) OrElse (n = nLastRow) Then
       ' send batch
    End If
Next n
```

Alternatively, you could set a variable to something unique in the last row and key off that, but the row count seems a safer way.